# Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet w/ two sheets.   Sheet 1 has a column of names and a column of numbers.  Sheet 2 references data from Sheet 1.

Sheet 1

```
+---+------+--------+
|   |  A   |   B    |
+---+------+--------+
| 1 | Name | Number |
+---+------+--------+
| 2 | Foo  |   10   |
```

In Sheet 2, I'm referencing Sheet 1. ie: ='Sheet 1':A2.  I have another spot where I need to get the number value thats associated to the cell referenced.

Sheet 2

```
+---+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|   |       A        |                    B                      |
+---+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Bar            | Baz                                       |
+---+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 2 | ='Sheet 1':A2  | Needs to look up what cell was referenced |
|   |                | in cell A2, and get the appropriate       |
|   |                | number column, next to that cell          |
|   |                | In this case it would be 'Sheet 1':B2     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a vLookup function

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,false)
```

Documentation can be found here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en